# ¿Como configurar la ruta CONFIRMATION de Payu para actualizar una base de datos con PHP - LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, webservice, payu

estoy integrando la pasarela de pago PAYU webcheckout.

Ya puedo enviar los datos de la compra a la plataforma de payu por medio del formulario que brinda payu webcheckout en la documentación. Es el siguiente...

```
<form method="post" action="https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/">
  <input name="merchantId"    type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['merchantId'] }}">
  <input name="accountId"     type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['accountId'] }}" >
  <input name="description"   type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['description'] }}">
  <input name="referenceCode" type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['referenceCode'] }}" >
  <input name="amount"        type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['amount'] }}"   >
  <input name="tax"           type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['tax'] }}"  >
  <input name="taxReturnBase" type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['taxReturnBase'] }}" >
  <input name="currency"      type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['currency'] }}" >
  <input name="signature"     type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['signature'] }}"  >
  <input name="test"          type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['test'] }}" >
  <input name="buyerFullName" type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['buyerFullName'] }}" >
  <input name="buyerEmail"    type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['buyerEmail'] }}" >
  <input name="telephone"    type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['telephone'] }}" >
  <input name="shippingAddress" type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['shippingAddress'] }}" >
  <input name="shippingCity"  type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['shippingCity'] }}" >
  <input name="shippingCountry" type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['shippingCountry'] }}" >
  <input name="responseUrl"   type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['responseUrl'] }}" >
  <input name="confirmationUrl" type="hidden"  value="{{ $dataPayu['confirmationUrl'] }}" >

  <section class="payment_proceso_tarjeta tarjeta_form_btn_payu">
     <button type="submit" class="btn_datos_envio">
        Pagar con 
        <img class="logo_payu" src="{{ asset('img/logos/payu.png')}}">
     </button>
  </section>
```

Esta es mi rutas en Laravel.

```
Route::post('/confirmation', 'ConfirmationController@confirmation');
```

Se supone que cuando payu termine de procesar el pago, me envia los datos de confirmacion a esa ruta de tipo POST, esos datos los capturo de en el controlador ConfirmationController con el metodo confirmation...así.

```
 public function confirmation(Request $request) {
     //Obtengo todos los datos aqui..

     $state_pol      = $request['state_pol'];

     // Verificao el estado de la compra para hacer la insercion en la base de datos

     if($state_pol == 4) {
        App\Producto::create([
            'id_categoria' => 1,
            'descripcion' => 'PRUEBA',
            'tags' => 'PRUEBA, PRUEBA',
            'referencia' => 'PRUEBA',
            'imagen' => 'PRUEBA',
            'precio' => 0,
            'descuento' => 0,
            'tallas' => 'PRUEBA',
            'colores' => 'PRUEBA',
            'tiempo_entrega' => 'PRUEBA',
            'imagenDescripcion' => 'PRUEBA',
            'cant_disponible' => 0,
            'fecha_creado' => 'PRUEBA'
        ]);
    }
 }
```

Se supone que con eso ya deberia insertar, pero no es asi, no se cual es el problema.
¿Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Primero asegurate que PayU esté llamando al callback que estás mencionando `/confirmation`. Coloca `dd($request->all());` en las primeras líneas de tu método `confirmation()`.

Comment: @HCK, pero para ver que arroja dd($request->all()) debe ser una ruta get ? Osea lo digo porque me sale un error al tratar de visualizar /confirmation que es una ruta post.

Comment: Buen punto, lo otro que puedes hacer es registrarlo en el log en lugar de arrojar un `dd()`: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info('Hay retorno desde PayU');` y luego revisa en `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: ooups, hee..puedes ayudarme o darme un tutorial donde expliquen eso, nunca he usado logs, tu disculpa.

Comment: Revisa este artículo: [Registro de actividad con Laravel Logging](https://styde.net/registro-de-actividad-con-laravel-logging/)

Comment: Ya lo probe y funciona en local, pero ahora hay otro problema, yo tengo la tienda publicada en heroku, de forma publica por que asi lo pide la documentacion para enviar los datos a confirmation, por que en local payu no puede enviarme los datos. En Heroku tengo el problema que no puedo ver el archivo laravel.log por que heroku toma los archivos desde github.

Answer (score 1):

La confirmación no admiten ningún tipo de redirección (ni htaccess) de modo que debe apuntar a un php

Yo tengo enviando la confirmacion a un archivo llamado payUconfirm.php que tengo en public/

1.boton de envio

```
<input name="confirmationUrl"    type="hidden"  value="https://misitio/payUconfirm.php" ></input>
```

2.en mi archivo payUconfirm.php

```
  require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';<br>
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
      ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
    //qui llegan todas las transacciones echas por PayU en metodo POST 
//instancia del controlador
    $test = new App\Http\Controllers\PayUController();
//acesso a las funciones
$test->paymentPayUConfirm($_POST);
```

Comment: https://laraveles.com/foro/viewtopic.php?id=6857

Comment: despues de la instancia de tu controlador puedes enviarle los datos normalmente,llamando sus funciones $test->mi Funcion();